# how to write the xml code to express the relation of city office?

Tags: xml, database

Detail the following relation in XML code: the continent Euro contains city offices in London, and Pairs. The head office is in Pairs.

Many thx for any respond. Feel free to check my solution so far.

```
<root>
<Continent='Euro'>
    <city='London'>
        <isHead>1</isHead>
    </city>

    <city='Pairs'>
        <isHead>0</isHead>
    </city>
</Continent>
</root>
```

Comment: *sniff*. *sniff*. Smells like homework to me. If it's not, please see [ask] for some detail on how to make a good question (this will in turn elicit better answers)

Comment: You can ask questions *about* your homework here, but you can't ask Stack Overflow to do your homework *for* you. You need to ask a specific question about a problem you're having doing this on your own and your question should show research effort. (See the link Sobrique provided).

Answer (score 1):

- That's not valid XML. You can have an element - which doesn't allow `=` and attributes. You can either have `<continent name="Euro">` or `<continent><name>Euro</name></continent>`
- Can you only ever have one office in London? It's quite a big place.

This is valid XML

```
<root>
  <region name="Euro">
    <office city="London" />
    <office city="Pairs" HQ="1" />
  </region>
</root>
```

Or you could perhaps:

```
<root>
  <continent name="Euro">
    <city name="London">
       <office name="Crown Plaza" />
    </city>
    <city name="Pairs">
        <office name="134 somestreet" HQ="1" />
    </city>
  </continent>
</root>
```